# Auth0 isAuthenticated() returns false after successful login redirect

Tags: javascript, auth0

I have a really simple Auth0 SPA integration, but `isAuthenticated()` always returns `false` even after a successful redirect after login. So I'm not getting any errors here, and I have added my URL in the app settings and checked that the ports match (`http://localhost:8888/auth0.html`).

```js
const auth0 = await createAuth0Client({ domain, client_id });

const isAuthenticated = await auth0.isAuthenticated();

if (!isAuthenticated) {
  loginButton.addEventListener("click", () =>
    auth0.loginWithRedirect({ redirect_uri: window.location.href })
  );
} else {
  logoutButton.addEventListener("click", () =>
    auth0.logout({ returnTo: window.location.href })
  );
}
```

Comment: I faced the same problem as you.  I overcame this problem by choosing my Application Type as `Single Page Application`. Could you please check the Setting of your Application?